# easy definition of Null terminator

Tags: null

could anybody please explain what the null terminator is in simple words?

I have read my definitions about it but having a hard time to understand it in my head

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Null terminators are often used in the context of arrays or data streams.

Every element of an array - or character in a string - is represented by a number.

Your null terminator - for strings: null character - marks the end of the senable data and has binairy value '0`. Same analogy applies to other array/stream or data types.

Example, you define an array with characters. This array is 100 characters long.

You put a string in it: "Hi!", which is only 3 characters long. To mark the rest being not relevant: you can put a null terminator after the "!", to indicate various function the rest is not relevant. This will help you print the value easier.